# Python Pandas df, best way to replace $, M and K in currency amount to change to int

Tags: python, regex, pandas, dataframe

I'm doing a personal project to practice pandas, and Beautiful soup, I scraped this info and have it in a pandas df like this:

```
0        €8.5M
1           €0
2        €9.5M
3          €2M
4         €21M
         ...  
16534    €1.8M
16535    €1.1M
16536    €550K
16537    €650K
16538    €1.1M
Name: Value, Length: 16539, dtype: object
0        €67K
1          €0
2        €15K
3        €11K
4        €13K
         ... 
16534     €3K
16535     €2K
16536     €2K
16537     €7K
16538     €3K
Name: Wage, Length: 16539, dtype: object
```

So in order to analyse this info I want to clean and transform this data into integers, what I could come up with was this:

```
df['Wage'] = df['Wage'].apply(lambda x: re.sub('€','',x))
df['Wage'] = df['Wage'].apply(lambda x: re.sub('K','000',x))

df['Value'] = df['Value'].apply(lambda x: re.sub('€','',x))
df['Value'] = df['Value'].apply(lambda x : re.sub('M','00000',x) if (('M' in x) and ('.' in x))else x)
df['Value'] = df['Value'].apply(lambda x : re.sub('[.]','',x))
df['Value'] = df['Value'].apply(lambda x : re.sub('M','000000',x))
df['Value'] = df['Value'].apply(lambda x : re.sub('K','000',x))

df['Wage'] = df['Wage'].astype(int)
df['Value'] = df['Value'].astype(int)
```

I replaced first the money sign, then check for dots so I can replace the M for 5 zeros, then the remaining M's for 6 zeros, then the K's for 3 zeros and then I do the type change into int.
But I feel like this is not a good way of doing this, What do you think? What would be a better way of doing this? I tried creating a function but couldn't do it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Updated Solution:

**New solution: Using [`.replace()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.replace.html) and [`astype()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.astype.html) only.

*Without relying on [`pd.eval`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.eval.html) for formula evaluation:***

**You can translate `M`, `K` to the corresponding magnitudes in exponential format:**

`K` converted to `e+03` in scientific notation

`M` converted to `e+06` in scientific notation

**(supports `integer` as well as `float` numbers in *any number of decimal places*)**

Then, convert the text in scientific notation to float type, followed by casting to integer for final required format, as follows:

```
df['Value'] = df['Value'].replace({'€': '', ' ': '', 'M': 'e+06', 'K': 'e+03'}, regex=True).astype(float).astype(int)
```

**Input data:**

```
         Value
0        €8.5M
1           €0
2        €9.5M
3          €2M
4         €21M
16534    €1.8M
16535    €1.1M
16536    €550K
16537    €650K
16538    €1.1M
```

**Output:**

```
print(df)

          Value
0       8500000
1             0
2       9500000
3       2000000
4      21000000
16534   1800000
16535   1100000
16536    550000
16537    650000
16538   1100000
```

#### Old Solution:

You can convert `M`, `K` to formula and then use [`pd.eval`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.eval.html) to evaluate the numeric values.

`K` converted to formula `* 1000`

`M` converted to formula `* 1000000`

In this way, we can support the base values with any number of decimal points (with or without decimal point and how long the fractional part could be).  We can just get the correct results from the formulas for all lengths of fractional parts after decimal points.

```
df['Value'] = df['Value'].str.replace('€', '')
df['Value'] = df['Value'].str.replace('M', ' * 1000000')
df['Value'] = df['Value'].str.replace('K', ' * 1000')
df['Value'] = df['Value'].map(pd.eval).astype(int)
```

---

Or simplified code in one line, thanks to @MustafaAydın's suggestion:

```
df['Value'] = df['Value'].replace({"€": "", "M": "*1E6", "K": "*1E3"}, regex=True).map(pd.eval).astype(int)
```

Result:

```
print(df)


          Value
0       8500000
1             0
2       9500000
3       2000000
4      21000000
16534   1800000
16535   1100000
16536    550000
16537    650000
16538   1100000
```

With the input sample data as follows:

```
         Value
0        €8.5M
1           €0
2        €9.5M
3          €2M
4         €21M
16534    €1.8M
16535    €1.1M
16536    €550K
16537    €650K
16538    €1.1M
```

Before the last step, we got:

```
               Value
0      8.5 * 1000000
1                  0
2      9.5 * 1000000
3        2 * 1000000
4       21 * 1000000
16534  1.8 * 1000000
16535  1.1 * 1000000
16536     550 * 1000
16537     650 * 1000
16538  1.1 * 1000000
```

Then we feed it to `pd.eval` for it to evaluate and convert to numeric value (in float) where we can further cast it to integer.

Comment: +1; can do replacements with a dict if you wish `df.Value.replace({"€": "", "M": "*1E6", "K": "*1E3"}, regex=True)` (and wrap `pd.eval` around this); but maybe yours is more readable.

Comment: @MustafaAydın  That's also good alternative way of doing it.  Thanks!

Comment: Thanks!, I didn't know the "*100000" formula, that solves my float problem, and I didn't know the dict replacement, that will make mi code much shorter, thanks to both!

Comment: Just one thing that I have noticed is that this makes the process slower, do you know why?

Comment: @LuisGan  Do you mean the `pd.eval` step ?  It is owing to it needs to evaluate formula and calculate the results.

Comment: @LuisGan  Updated with a new solution using simpler functions.  Let me know whether it runs faster in your data environment.

Answer (score 1):

You can replace the values in one regex `Series.str.replace()` pass using

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'Value':['€8.5M', '€0','€9.5M','€2M','€21M','€1.8M','€1.1M','€550K','€650K','€1.1M']})

def repl(x):
    if not x.group(2):
        return x.group(1)
    if x.group(2) == 'K':
        return str(int(float(x.group(1)) * 1000))
    else:
        return str(int(float(x.group(1)) * 1000000))

>>> df['Value'].str.replace(r'^€?(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)([KM])?$', lambda x: repl(x), regex=True).astype(int)
0     8500000
1           0
2     9500000
3     2000000
4    21000000
5     1800000
6     1100000
7      550000
8      650000
9     1100000
Name: Value, dtype: int32
```

The `^€?(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)([KM])?$` regex matches

- `^` - start of string
- `€?` - an optional `€`
- `(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)`  - Group 1: one or more digits and then an optional sequence of a `.` and one or more digits
- `([KM])?` - an optional Group 2: `K` or `M`
- `$` - end of string.

If there is no `K` or `M`, the Group 1 value is returned. If there is `K`, the number in Group 1 is multiplied by 1000, else, by 1000000.